# Jquery Game - how to keep object inside bounds

Tags: jquery, html, runtime-error, game-physics, keyboard-events

I wanted to get a feel of a simple jquery game so I pulled an example to test.
The soldier would move prior to changing the following:

**Initally was:**

```
<p><img id="soldier" style="left: 50px; position: absolute; top: 250px" 
height=90 width=100 border=0 hspace=0 src="soldier.jpg"/></p>
```

**Now is:**

```
<p><img id='soldier' src='soldier.jpg'></p>
```

css:

```
#soldier {z-index: 0; left: 100px; top: 250px; height:90px; width:100px; border:0;}
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The issue I have(aside the recent image position change above) I get an error that says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

for line:

```
var maxLeft = parseInt($("#box").css('width')) -parseInt($("#box").css('border-left-width')) - parseInt($("#soldier").width());
```

for the soldier's height. I am using a format that I have used in a past program **but neither format of:**

```
var maxLeft = parseInt($("#box").css('width')) -parseInt($("#box").css('border-left-width')) - parseInt($("#soldier").width());
```

OR

```
var maxLeft = parseInt($("#box").css('width')) -parseInt($("#box").css('border-left-width')) - parseInt(obj.css("width"));
```

works. I want to keep my soldier within the box while the user moves him.

https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4990/

The movements is found in my first function moveObj

[image]

My error:

[image]

Comment: I don't see _Uncaught ReferenceError_ in fiddle. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` usually appears when jQuery is not included before the code.

Comment: I recopied my file in jsfiddle... I see the error but that isn't the error I get.

Comment: Also.. it shows the error commented out but it really isn't

Comment: @Regent I tried adding: <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> but I get error

Comment: What error? Did you add `<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` before your code?

Comment: This gave me no errors but didn't fix my `$ is not defined` error: `<script type="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: For first jquery call I get error: `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and no I didn't have this in my code prior to my error at the beginning. But when I added it to top right bellow `<head>` it doesn't work

Comment: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` is correct link, so you should figure out why it is not loaded on your page. Without jQuery's script jQuery's code will not work.

Comment: Ya the ajax worked. I just missed a part. By format of: `<script var maxLeft = parseInt($("#box").css('width')) -parseInt($("#box").css('border-left-width')) - parseInt($("#soldier").width());` the errors are gone but the soldier doesn't move now ... ..

Comment: My moveObj if statements are not working. If they are commented out the guy moves but not inside boundaries :/

Comment: Well, you can debug your code. Writing the code is not only about creating something but is also about debugging and fixing errors in code. Your original question is solved now.

Comment: Error yes but whole question no. Thanks. I will look more into the topic then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess hard coding values(thought not the best) worked for me.

```
function moveObj(obj_name, Xpix, Ypix) 
{    
  obj = document.getElementById(obj_name);
  var Xpix0 = 0;
  var Ypix0 = 0;

  var px = parseInt(obj.style.left) + Xpix;     
  var py = parseInt(obj.style.top) + Ypix;
  var px0 = parseInt(obj.style.left) + Xpix0;
  var py0 = parseInt(obj.style.top) + Xpix0;

  if(px >= 300 && px <= 1070){
  obj.style.left = px;}
   else{
    obj.style.left = px0;}
    //alert(py);    
  if(py >= 10 && py <= 620){
    obj.style.top = py;}
    else{
     obj.style.top = py0;}
}
```